# Create several objects at once Django Rest Framework Generic Views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using Django Rest Framework. I'm trying to create a `ListCreateAPIView` to create several objects at once but nothing I've found so far seems to work and not sure why.

```py
#My view
class MyListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Mymodel.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)

    # tried this with no luck
    def get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=None, many=False, partial=False):
        if data is not None:
            data.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            return super(MyListCreateView, self).get_serializer(instance=instance, data=data, many=True, partial=partial)
        else:
            return super(MyListCreateView, self).get_serializer(instance=instance, many=True, partial=partial)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user_obj = self.request.user
        serializer.save(user=user_obj)

#my serializer
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the top:

- This is a regular `View` with a dynamic `many` argument. Argument `many` itself doesn't make your serializer create multiple objects at once. For `many` to work as expected we need `ListSerializer`.

  ```
   class MyView(ListCreateAPIView):
       ...
       def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           data = request.data
           serializer = MySerializer(data=data, many=isinstance(data, list))
           serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
           serializer.save()
  ```
- Create `ListSerializer` with `create` function like the following:

  ```
   class MyListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
       ...
       def create(self, validated_data):
           items = [MyModel(**item) for item in validated_data]
           return MyModel.objects.bulk_create(items)
  ```
- And finally in your main serializer's `Meta` class set `list_serializer_class` field value to `MyListSerializer`.

  ```
   class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
       ...
       def create(self, validated_data):
           return MyModel.objects.create(**validated_data)

       class Meta:
           list_serializer_class = MyListSerializer
  ```

*You can read up on the custom serializer behavior [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior)*