# How to create multiple model instances with Django Rest Framework using generics?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-generic-views

I would like to save and update multiple instances using the Django Rest Framework with one API call, **using generics.**
I have tried the solutions proposed for the following links, but I would very much appreciate some help.

1. [Create several objects at once with Django Framework Generic Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69603863/create-several-objects-at-once-django-rest-framework-generic-views)
2. [How to save multiple objects with Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666199/how-do-i-create-multiple-model-instances-with-django-rest-framework/40253309)
3. [Django Rest Framework Doc for serializing multiple objects](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects)

```
    # serializers.py 
    class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Asset
            fields = '__all__'
            #fields = ('id', 'name', 'amount')
        
    # views.py
    class CreateAssetView(generics.CreateAPIView):
        serializer_class = AssetSerializer(many=True)
        def perform_create(self, serializer):
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
    
    # urls.py
    urlpatterns = [
        ...
        path('create_asset', CreateAssetView.as_view()),
    ]
```